# Creating stored procedure that returns the row count only

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2016

I want to query a table and get the total number of rows that fit the given query:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetTransactionsFromTransactionRecordForMonthYear]
    @Guid   nvarchar(50),
    @Month  int,
    @Year   int
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON; 

    SELECT  *
    FROM    Company.TransactionRecord
    WHERE   Company.TransactionRecord.CorporationId = @Guid and 
    MONTH( Company.TransactionRecord.TransactionDate ) = @Month AND 
    YEAR( Company.TransactionRecord.TransactionDate ) = @Year
    SELECT @@ROWCOUNT
END
```

When I run this, SSMS returns back 5783 rows but the return value is 5781. I would have thought that the total number of records would match the return value.

[image]

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. How do I fix this where it just returns the total number of records for that query?

Thank you!

Comment: ` SELECT @@ROWCOUNT` will constitute to `1 row`. Did you do another ` SELECT @@ROWCOUNT` after execute the stored procedure ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with Linker that a scalar valued function is a better approach.  I just think that the proposed code is a total mess and should be cleaned up as well:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].GetTransactionsFromTransactionRecordForMonthYear
(
    @Guid  uniqueidentifer,
    @Month int,
    @Year  int
)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN    
    DECLARE @row_count INT;
  
    SELECT @row_count = COUNT(*)
    FROM Company.TransactionRecord tr
    WHERE tr.CorporationId = @Guid AND
          tr.TransactionDate >= DATEFROMPARTS(@Year, @Month, 1) AND
          tr.TransactionDate < DATEADD(MONTH, 1, DATEFROMPARTS(@Year, @Month, 1));

    RETURN @row_count;
END;
```

Notes:

- SQL has a type for unique identifiers.  Presumably, that is what your GUID is.  If it is a string, then use a string.
- The date arithmetic is sargable (i.e. better for the optimizer) if it uses direct date comparisons.
- Repeating the entire table name for each column just makes the code hard to write and read.  Use table aliases!

Comment: Perfect! Tyvm for the info, it's a great help!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to continue to use a stored procedure, just `select count(*)` instead of `select *`:

```
 CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetTransactionsFromTransactionRecordForMonthYear]
    @Guid   nvarchar(50),
    @Month  int,
    @Year   int
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON; 

    SELECT  count(*) rows
    FROM  Company.TransactionRecord tr
    WHERE tr.CorporationId = @Guid  
      AND tr.TransactionDate >= datefromparts(@year,@month,1)
      AND tr.TransactionDate < dateadd(month,1,datefromparts(@year,@month,1))

END
```

Comment: tyvm for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the exact problem with your store procedure but you can try scalar valued function to return row count. Please check my code and try it and let men know.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GetTransactionsFromTransactionRecordForMonthYear]
(
    @Guid  nvarchar(50),
    @Month int,
    @Year  int
)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN    
  DECLARE @Value INT
  
  SET @Value=(SELECT  COUNT(*)
              FROM Company.TransactionRecord
              WHERE Company.TransactionRecord.CorporationId = @Guid and 
              MONTH( Company.TransactionRecord.TransactionDate ) = @Month AND 
              YEAR(Company.TransactionRecord.TransactionDate ) = @Year);
  RETURN @Value;
END
```